# How to add a function to yii2 models?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 project, i've used gii to generate crud operations for a model named account.

now i want to change(or add a new one) the delete function so that it doesn't delete the 
record from the database but instead flag it as deleted, and i'm not sure where to make my changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in `actionDelete` of your controller.

```
$model->deleted = 1;
$model->save();
```

Comment: This is an incorrect approach (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29366838/1469208)). You should do this in model itself. You shouldn't do this in a controller, to (a) not break up MVC design pattern and (b) to make such change available for all controllers (and other methods; thus in model) instead of repeating your code in all controllers or everywhere, where you deal with model. This kind of operations should be completely invisible to controllers layer (that's why we should implement this in models), because one mistake (not adding this code to single controller) ruins everything.

Answer (score 4):

You should do this in model's code itself, by overriding [`beforeDelete()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete()-detail) event. Something like this:

```
public function beforeDelete()
{
    if (parent::beforeDelete()) {
        $this->deleted = true;
        $this->save();

        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(*written from my memory, not tested, but should work*)

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't care about setting that in controller and keep that in memory. So it's more correct according to MVC pattern. But truth is many will continue to use Alex answer just because it's shorter and faster to right.

Comment: Shorter and easier answers aren't always the best one! :> I'm simply thrilling only thinking, that in future, in such organised project, someone forgets to copy this code to new controller and ruins entire application by actually deleting a record, instead of changing it's flag! :> Plus, this solution makes use of Yii's powerful event system and not many PHP frameworks out there utilizes this power. OK, I must admit, I just _love_ Yii! :>

Comment: Yes, you are right, and you can always put repeating code in behavior and just attach where it's needed.